# Invoke aws api gateway from step function using IAM role auth type

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-step-functions, api-gateway

I have use case where I have to invoke the api gatway rest endpoint in other aws account, they have given me a role to assume,

I am thinking of two options:

1. generate the request from the lambda and call the api
2. use step function to invoke the api

Q1. I personally think option 2 is better but what are your view on this

Q2. I have trouble invoking the rest endpoint from the step function here is my step function definition

```
{
  "Comment": "A description of my state machine",
  "StartAt": "API Gateway Invoke",
  "States": {
    "API Gateway Invoke": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::apigateway:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "ApiEndpoint": "endpoint",
        "Method": "GET",
        "Path": "path",
        "AuthType": "IAM_ROLE"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

IAM role trust relationships

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "states.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

Policy to assume role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
        "Resource": "role_arn"
    }
}
```

when I execute the step function I get this error response

```
{
  "resourceType": "apigateway",
  "resource": "invoke",
  "error": "ApiGateway.403",
  "cause": {
    "Message": "User:rolearn/hUAiLwbfPOsSKqarBDcdelSpeGIbyiZA is not authorized to access this resource"
  }
}
```

I have tried giving the full execution invoke permission to the step function but it didn't help
I am stuck any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently step function doesn't support cross account integration between step function and API gateway without resource policy.

My guess is the step function is failing to assume the role.